# how to get lat lng value separately from received JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I am getting below JSON response from google map api in a var like 'obj'. When i alert obj.name i got "Pancakes on the Rocks". If I need icon i write like this - obj.icon . But how can i get separate value of lat/lng. When i alert obj.geometry.location i got - (-33.87054,151.198815) But i need them separately not like this. Any suggestions.
Thanks all.

```
{
"html_attributions" : [],
"results" : [
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.87054,
           "lng" : 151.198815
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
     "id" : "c71365287e7606bd21a3311d21fda087830b7813",
     "name" : "Pancakes on the Rocks",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : true
     },
     "photos" : [
      ...



function createMarkers(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    createResultMarker(results[i]);
    }
  } 
}



function createResultMarker(obj) {

  alert('title: ' + obj.name);  // Alert correct name.
  alert(obj.geometry.location);
  alert(obj.geometry.location.lat);

  distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(init_lat, init_lng, obj.geometry.location.lat, obj.geometry.location.lng);

}
```

Comment: Just `obj.geometry.location.lat` and `obj.geometry.location.lng`???

Comment: nope :( it gives : 
function (){
"use strict";
return this[a]}

Comment: Then your `obj` is not the plain (parsed) JSON response you posted. Please show us the whole code ([edit] your question)

Comment: I didn't say that you should post the whole JSON file, but the *JavaScript code* that does load it and where you put your alerts!

Comment: To debug such problems, `alert()` is not the best option. Better use `console.log(obj.geometry)` and open the javascript console in your browser. You can then click on the console output and inspect the object in a tree view, which will give you a hint about what is wrong.

Comment: @Peter: k giving it a try

Comment: `obj.geometry.location.lat()` and `obj.geometry.lng()` should work. You are not actually using the JSON you have posted, you are using the google.maps.places service, which returns [google.maps.LatLng objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `obj.geometry.location.lat()` and `obj.geometry.lng()`, they are functions.

You are not actually using the JSON you have posted, you are using the google.maps.places service, which returns [google.maps.LatLng objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)